# Assign aliases using FOR in Windows cmd.exe

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, alias

I've been trying to use a loop to create multiple aliases without success. I'm not a professional, please bear with me... Does anyone know what's wrong in my code or how I can implement this in the command prompt? I know how to do this in PowerShell but I'm trying to reproduce the code for cmd. Here's the code:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR %%G IN (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) DO (
    DOSKEY %%GG=cd %%GG:\
)
```

Here's what I get as a result when running the macro:

[image]

Comment: So what do you see or experience with the batch file?

Comment: I've just added a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining `DOSKEY %%GG=cd %%GG:\` (with double Gs) which expands to `DOSKEY aG=cd aG:\`, `DOSKEY bG=cd bG:\`... so you must type `aG` in order to change into the drive `aG:` (which is not a valid drive letter). Same to other drives

If you run [`for /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) you'll see that variables in for loop have only one letter, just like how command line parameters are composed of a single digit

```
FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

  %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
```

Moreover to change the current drive you use only the drive letter instead of `cd`. That means to change to the current directory on A: just run `A:`. `CD A:` won't work (as expected). However if you want to force changing **both the current drive and current directory** then [use the `/D` option](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)

Here's the fixed version

```bat
@ECHO OFF

FOR %%G IN (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) DO (
    DOSKEY %%G=%%G:
    rem Or DOSKEY %%G=cd /D %%G:
)
```